# ARC: How do you release a WindowController when the user closes the Window?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying to translate some old code to ARC.  The old code does this in the WindowController:

```
@interface PreferencesController () <NSWindowDelegate>

@end

@implementation PreferencesController

    -(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification*) notification {

        [self autorelease];
    }

@end
```

My AppDelegate has a strong pointer to the WindowController:

```
@property(strong) PreferencesController* preferencesCtrl;
```

In PreferencesController, do I need to declare a (weak) pointer back to the AppDelegate, and then do something like this:

```
-(void) windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[self appDelegate] setPreferencesCtrl:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your thoughts are right.

But I can give you make it more simple.

Set your application delegate as NSWindowDelegate.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>

@property (strong) PreferencesController* preferencesCtrl;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)doAction
{
  // create window
  // ...
  self.preferencesCtrl.window.delegate = self; // set window delegate
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification 
  {
   self.preferencesCtrl=nil;
  }

@end
```

**UPD**
Since you are already using NSWindowDelegate methods, I suggest you to create another delegate protocol, say `PreferenceControllerDelegate`

```
//in PreferenceController.h before class interface
@class PreferenceControllerDelegate

@protocol PreferenceControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)preferenceControllerWindowWillClose:(PreferenceControllerDelegate *)sender;

@end 

@interface PreferenceController : NSWindowController

//...

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<PreferenceControllerDelegate> delegate;

//...

@end
```

That would be much proper.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My PreferencesController is already the delegate for my Preferences window(the PreferencesController does a couple of things in windowDidLoad), and IB will not let me drag the delegate outlet of the Preferences window to more than one object.  I looked around and there are some solutions, e.g. MultiDelegate, but they seem overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@autoreleasepool` to force an immediate `dealloc` when you nil the pointer.

```
-(void) windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //[[self appDelegate] setPreferencesCtrl:nil];
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSApp delegate] setPreferencesCtrl:nil];
    }
}
```

You can also access the app delegate through the `NSApp` singleton using `NSApp.delegate`, which is `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, though I guess you'd have to typecast it to avoid a warning.  Either way.